# Meteor: Error: ENOENT when trying to access an image using node-gd

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I can't understand why I'm getting this "Error: ENOENT" error.  Here is my Meteor server method:

```
  createImage: function(coords) {
    console.log('createImage')
    console.log(coords.area)
    console.log(coords.x)
    console.log(coords.y)
    console.log(coords.x2)
    console.log(coords.y2)
    console.log(coords.w)
    console.log(coords.h)

    var gd = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gd');
    var path = Meteor.npmRequire('path');
    var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');

    var source = 'forrest.png';
    var target = 'compimages';


     if (path.exists(target)) fs.unlink(target);

        gd.openPng(source, function(png, path) {
                              if(png) {
                                 console.log(png)
                                 console.log(path)
                              }
                           }
        );

    }
```

Here is the output I get from it on the terminal:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
I20140827-15:30:18.451(-7)? createImage
I20140827-15:30:18.455(-7)? 27888
I20140827-15:30:18.456(-7)? 242 
I20140827-15:30:18.459(-7)? 164
I20140827-15:30:18.459(-7)? 410
I20140827-15:30:18.459(-7)? 330
I20140827-15:30:18.459(-7)? 168
I20140827-15:30:18.460(-7)? 166
W20140827-15:30:18.527(-7)? (STDERR) path.exists is now called `fs.exists`.
I20140827-15:30:18.547(-7)? { [Error: ENOENT, open 'forrest.png'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'forrest.png' }
I20140827-15:30:18.548(-7)? undefined
```

These are the directories within ~/myapp/server/

```
me@ubuntu:~/myapp/server$ ls
compimages  forrest.png  privateimages  server.js  user-setup.js
```

I want to access forrest.png and use node-gd to cut a section of it out based on the coords passed in.

As far as I understand it this error means that there is a directory missing.  The png file I'm trying to access is in the same directory as the .js file calling it (they are both in ~/myapp/server/ so to me it doesn't look like that's the problem.  The only thing I can see is that the path is undefined.  I've got that installed though:

```
me@ubuntu:~/myapp/packages/npm/npm/node_modules$ ls
node-gd  path
```

Can anyone see what's going on with this?  I'm using Meteor 0.9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `console.log(process.cwd())` in your server code you will notice that the current working directory of your Meteor app is `project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server` however your code assumes that the CWD is `project/server`.

What you can do is prefixing your paths with the project root server folder which is obtained by going 5 level ups in the filesystem hierarchy.

```
var projectRootServer="../../../../../server";
var source=projectRootServer+"forrest.png";
```

This is not very elegant but it works.

Unrelated but it seems that `path.exists` has been deprecated in favor of `fs.exists`, you should fix this too.

Comment: Thanks again! :) ... I wonder how much longer I would've been at that for!  That seems to be working now.  Just need to try and get it doing something with the image, something for another day!  Thank you!